# Same code on same JDK compiles on Eclipse but causes inconvertible types on Netbeans, IDEA or command line

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, netbeans, javac

Code snippet is this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Callable<?> callable;
        final ExecutorService someExecutor = null;
        Collection<Callable<?>> tasks = new LinkedList<Callable<?>>();
        int timeoutInSeconds = 10;
        try {
            for (Future<?> f : someExecutor.invokeAll(
                    (Collection<? extends Callable<Callable<?>>>) tasks,
                    timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                f.get();
            }

        } catch (java.util.concurrent.CancellationException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile from command line

`javac Test.java`

I get the following error:

```
Test.java:17: inconvertible types
found   : java.util.Collection<java.util.concurrent.Callable<?>>
required: java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.util.concurrent.Callable<?>>>
                (Collection<? extends Callable<Callable<?>>>) tasks,
                                                              ^
```

I also get the same error when I compile with IDEA or Netbeans. *But* eclipse thinks everythink is ok and runs normally. I triple checked that all 3 use the same JDK (1.6u45). So what does eclipse do differently?

Comment: Besides the JDK, did you check the version compatibility of your projects ?

Comment: @Berger yes it's 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses an own [Java compiler ECJ](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) which sometimes behaves differently than `javac`.

Comment: Can I skip that? Any more details? What's that "own" compiler? Any links?

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis see updated answer. You can't skip it as far as I know but you can try to update to the newest Eclipse version if you haven't already.

Comment: I downloaded Mars.1 (4.5.1) yesterday, so yes, I guess it's the newest.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the JVM with -vm option in your eclipse.ini, does eclipse has the same behavior?  This doesn't work.

Try navigate to Preferences->Java->Compiler->Error/Warnings, in the right panel, search "Unchecked generic type operation", set level from "Ignored" to "Error". Have a rebuilt, you will get the same result.

Comment: That should have been a comment, not an answer, but anyway, no it's not the same, it  causes an error: `Could not create the JVM`. And of course IDE does not start.

Comment: that maybe because you have a wrong configuration. You should set jdk1.6.xx/bin. For example, -vm C:/jdk1.6.x/bin